# How can I use LINQ to project this parent and children object model into a flat, single object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to flatten out a simple class that has a parent + child array, into a single class.

#### From:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PewPew> PewPews { get; set; }
}

public class PewPew
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
}

- 1 | Fred | { { AAA | xxx }, { BBB | yyy } }
- 2 | Bill | { { CCC | zzz } }
```

#### To:

```
public class FooProjection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PewPewName { get; set; }
    public PewPewWhatever { get; set; }
}

- 1 | Fred | AAA | xxx
- 1 | Fred | BBB | yyy
- 2 | Bill | CCC | zzz
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The pure Linq approach

You can use the [**`SelectMany()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) overload that allows you to specify a result selector that is called on every element in the collection:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable, flattens the
>   resulting sequences into one sequence, and invokes a result selector
>   function on each element therein.

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
var fooProjections = foos.SelectMany(x => x.PewPews, (foo, pew) => new FooProjection() 
{ 
    Id = foo.Id, 
    Name = foo.Name,
    PewPewName = pew.Name,
    PewPewWhatever = pew.Whatever 
}).ToList();
```

This approach is the most concise, but takes some time getting used to, especially if you have not been working with Linq a lot.

**Edit:**

As per @AS-CII's comment it might be more readily understandable (and this is important for maintaining the code base) to just use a loop and a simple projection with `Select()`. If someone has a problem with Linq in this scenario at all, two nested loop would do as well. I'll show both for completeness.

### Using a foreach loop and a Select projection

Just iterate over all Foos and create a new `FooProjection` for each `PewPew` in the current item. Add all of them to the `fooProjections` list that is in scope. This approach uses a Linq projection to map from each `PewPew` to a `FooProjection`, using the `foo` from the foreach loop.

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
List<FooProjection> fooProjections = new List<FooProjection>();

foreach(var foo in foos)
{
    var someFooProjections = foo.PewPews.Select(x => new FooProjection() 
    { 
        Id = foo.Id, 
        Name = foo.Name, 
        PewPewName = x.Name, 
        PewPewWhatever = x.Whatever 
    });
    fooProjections.AddRange(someFooProjections);
}
```

### Using two nested foreach loops

Just use two `foreach` loops, the outer iterating over the Foos, the inner over the PewPews collection in the current foo - add a new `FooProjection` to the `fooProjections` list that is in scope. This approach does not make use of Linq at all.

```
List<FooProjection> fooProjections = new List<FooProjection>();
foreach (var foo in foos)
    foreach (var pew in foo.PewPews)
    {
        fooProjections.Add(new FooProjection()
        {
            Id = foo.Id,
            Name = foo.Name,
            PewPewName = pew.Name,
            PewPewWhatever = pew.Whatever
        });
    }
```

Comment: Show him the '*more words*' way of doing this. It is cleaner and much easier to understand :)

Comment: @BrokenGlass the verbose way would be nice also (to compare) but i'm very kewl with that also. What happens if some of the Foo's have a null PewPews property?

Comment: Added a comparison with pure linq, a single `foreach` loop and two nested `foreach` loops

Comment: @Pure.Krome: You will have to check for `PewPew` not to be null in all 3 approaches, easiest is by replacing `foos` with `foos.Where( x=> x.PewPews!=null)`

Comment: The all LINQ version is plenty easy to understand, you just have to understand LINQ. Having to break it down is like saying show him the 'more words' way of doing it and break it down into IL code, then assembly...valid concept, but in this case, I'd say the LINQ is fine; you've gotta learn the language.

Answer (score 6):

I find query expressions with multiple `from`s far easier to write than calls to `SelectMany`. They compile to the same thing.

```
List<Foo> foos = GetFoos();

var projected = 
    from foo in foos
    from pewPew in foo.PewPews
    select new FooProjection
        { Id = foo.Id, 
          Name = foo.Name, 
          PewPewName = pewPew.Name, 
          PewPewWhatever = pewPew.Whatever };
```

Comment: That's pretty kewl too, actually :) LIKE!